# Array de Arrays en condicional if

Tags: javascript, array

estoy comenzando a programar en JavaScript, y llevo unos días estancado en un ejercicio y perdiendo un poco la cordura por que no soy capaz de encontrar que está fallando por mucho que intente solucionarlo o buscar alternativas.
Básicamente el ejercicio consiste en realizar un Bingo con 15 números aleatorios en el cartón, y otro número aleatorio entre 1 y 99 que varía entre cada turno, y en caso de que el número aleatorio de ese turno coincida con alguno de los que tenga el usuario en el cartón, lo remplace con una X.
Mi problema viene cuando hago el condicional if entre el número aleatorio de cada turno y los números del cartón. No entiendo por que no lo comprueba, y pese a que el número se encuentre en el cartón, no lo remplaza. He creado 3 bucles for por que tenía la idea de que estoy accediendo mal al indice y contenido del Array de Arrays que es el cartón pero...tampoco logro que funcione.
Si alguien me pudiese echar una mano, lo agradecería muchísimo.
Gracias de antemano!.

```
let bingNums = [];
let cartonNums = [];
let random = [];

function generateCarton () {
    for (let i = 0; i < 15; i++ ){
        let random = Math.random()
        random = random * 25 + 1 
        random = Math.trunc(random)
        cartonNums[i] = random;
    }
    cartonNums = [
        cartonNums.slice(0,5).join(' - '),
        cartonNums.slice(5,10).join(' - '),
        cartonNums.slice(10,15).join(' - ')
  ]
}

function randomNumTurn () {
    for (let x = 0; x < 99; x++ ){
        let random = Math.random()
        random = random * 25 + 1 
        random = Math.trunc(random)
        bingNums[x] = random;
    }
     random = bingNums[Math.floor(Math.random() * bingNums.length)]
}

function greetings () {
    let askName = prompt("Hola! ¿cual es su nombre?")
    if (askName === null || askName === "" || askName === " " || !isNaN(askName)){
        console.log("Debe introducir su nombre, valores númericos no serán aceptados.")
    } else {
        console.log("Bien " + askName + ", el Bingo comienza.")
        generateCarton()
        randomNumTurn()
        keep()
    }
}

function keep () { 
    for (let i = 0; i < cartonNums.length; i++){
        console.log(cartonNums[i].toString())
      }
    let askCarton = prompt("¿Desea mantener este cartón? Si / No")
    if (askCarton.toLowerCase() === "si" || askCarton.toLowerCase() === "s"){
        console.log("Bien!")
        play()
    } else if (askCarton.toLowerCase() === "no" || askCarton.toLowerCase() === "n"){
        console.log("Cambiando cartón...")
        cartonNums = [];
        generateCarton()
        keep()
    } else if (askCarton === null || askCarton === " " || askCarton === "" || isNaN(cartonNums)){
        console.log("Debes responder con Si o No.")
        keep()
    }
}

function play() {
    console.log("Su cartón actual es: \n")
    for (let i = 0; i < cartonNums.length; i++){
        console.log(cartonNums[i])
    }
    console.log("El número de este turno es: " + random)
    for (let i = 0; i < cartonNums.length; i++){
        for (let x = 0; x < cartonNums[x].length; x++){
            for (let  j = 0; j < cartonNums[i][x].length; j++){
                if (cartonNums[i][x][j] === random.toString()){
                    console.log("Tienes este número en tu cartón!")
                    cartonNums[i][x][j].replace(random, "X")
                    console.log(cartonNums[i])
                    again()
                    break;
                } else if (cartonNums[i][x][j] !== random){
                    console.log("El número no se encuentra en su cartón /:")
                    for (let i = 0; i < cartonNums.length; i++){
                        console.log(cartonNums[i].toString())
                    }
                    again()
                    break;
                }
                break;
            }
            break;
        }
        break;
    }
}

function again (){
    if (confirm("¿Desea sacar otra bola?")) {
        random = [];
        randomNumTurn()
        play()
      } else {
        console.clear
        console.log("Está bien, adiós.")
        console.log("Su cartón ha quedado así: " )
        for (let i = 0; i < cartonNums.length; i++){
            console.log(cartonNums[i])
        }
      }
}

greetings()
```

Comment: Seguramente porque estás comparando string contra number.  Reemplaza la triple igualdad (===) por una doble (==)

Comment: @Yussef continúa igual.. gracias de todas formas!